# How is java_lang_StrictMath.h generated in openjdk

Tags: java

How is `java_lang_StrictMath.h` generated in `openjdk`. If I want to create a new `TargetMath.c` file in jdk/src/share/native/java/lang in `openjdk`, how do I generate a similar `java_lang_TargetMath.h.` Thanks.